# Python multiprocessing: calling mpi executable and distributing over cores

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use python's multiprocessing approach to speed up a program I am working on.

The python code runs in serial, but has calls to an mpi executable. It is these calls that I would like to do in parallel as they are independent of one another.

For each step the python script takes I have a set of calculations that must be done by the mpi program.

For example, if I am running over 24 cores, I would like the python script to call 3 instances of the mpi executable each running on 8 of the cores. Each time one mpi executable run ends, another instance is started until all members of a queue are finished.

I am just getting started using multiprocessing, and I am fairly certain this is possible, but I am not sure on how to go about doing it. I can set up a queue and have multiple processes start, it's the adding of the next set of calculations into the queue and starting them that is the issue.

If some kind soul could give me some pointers, or some example code, I'd be most obliged!

Comment: I'm a bit confused here ... Does the input of one mpi run depend on the output of another or are they all independent?  If they're all independent, it seems like you should just be able to write a function to start a single mpi job (e.g. using `subprocess`) and then call that function from a `multiprocessing.Pool` that is runs 3 processes.

Comment: They are all independent. But, in this example, I have more than 3 of these calculations to do for each step in the python script. What I wasn't sure on is how to limit the python multiprocessing to only run 3 instances of the mpi executable at any one time. I see that multiprocessing.Pool is the key. Thanks!